# JPA / OpenJPA Same value in all rows

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I have a problem with OpenJPA

I try to read all rows from a table but the primary key has always a same value(value = 0)!?!?!?

```
for (Object o : em.createQuery("select x from AnnouncementsEntry x")
                .getResultList()) {
            //alway returns "0" in every row
                long id = ((AnnouncementsEntry) o).getEntryId();
```

my entry:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long entryId;
```

Comment: Activate logging of SQL, check what query is performed, run it against the database, check the results.

Comment: i cecked the sql log and executed sql works. After some testing it returns null values on the primary key. All other values will transfer to the entry.

Comment: What version of OpenJPA are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This is way old, but I'm fairly certain that the problem was how your Entities were enhanced. More than likely you used an eclipse plugin that has [some problems](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1879).

To anyone else having this problem, please checkout the [OpenJPA enhancement docs](http://openjpa.apache.org/entity-enhancement.html).